# Rebase *** RelocateImage failed

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

When building a project with Visual Studio, I noticed a nasty little post linker error, with windows Rebase

`REBASE: *** RelocateImage failed (dll name) Image may be currupted`

I was unable to get a usable build. I tried erasing all the object files and rebuilding, with the same problem. This happened only under certain compiling configurations, but was consistently happening for about 4 hours, with various different projects with the same several compiler configurations.

After about four hours of the problem, it just magically stopped happening. I've been searching the web for a good explanation of what this error actually means and how best to fix it, but I haven't found anything significant.

While my project now works fine, I'm mostly concerned because I have no explanation for the problem, and fear its return. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic powers tell me you are linking with the /FIXED switch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w368ysh2.aspx Fixed modules cannot be rebased. You get lucky sometimes and rebasing isn't needed.