# Error code 487 (ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS) when using VirtualAllocEX

Tags: winapi, memory-management, error-code

I'm trying to use VirtualAllocEx(). When I set `dwSize` (the third parameter) to a number larger than about 63 MB, it cause to generate error code 487 when I look at `GetLastError()`. However, it works with smaller sizes such as 4MB.

Here is part of my code:

```
VirtualAllocEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,
               (LPVOID)(INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
               dwImageSize, 
               MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
               PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

In the case that I used a 4MB EXE file, the LPVOID return value is `0x00400000`, but in other cases (20MB or bigger file) it returns `0x00000000`.

1. Is there a maximum value for the `dwSize` parameter?
2. Is there any other solution for my problem, such as another function?

Comment: The third parameter you mean. Since you are requesting a particular start address the failure could be because your size request would cause the allocation to bump into something else that has already been allocated.

Comment: Agreed.  In 99% of situations, you should not specify a start address at all, let the OS decide where the memory should be allocated.

Comment: Strange, allocating at OptionalHeader.ImageBase should always fail.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : but i want to Start from the address that INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase say. by your mean, how let the OS specify the location?

Comment: Why do you want to allocate at that specific address? What are you trying to accomplish? You do realize that the PE base address is only a "preferred" address and not a guarantee, right? The OS sometimes has to avoid conflicts by re-basing and fixing up a module while loading it if the "preferred" address is already in use.

Comment: To let the OS pick the allocation location, simply set the `lpAddress` parameter to NULL.

Comment: Your bounty seems pointless unless you respond to the comments. It's quite easy for us to answer your question, once you ask it properly. You need to supply an SSCCE, and some good reason why you would expect to be able to reserve memory at an address that it would seem is already reserved. The reason why you did not get an answer is not because there was not enough reputation on offer, but because your question was incomplete. Fix the question and you will get an answer.

Comment: @mostafa88 Was my answer below helpful? I was guessing at the ultimate purpose of your code, but I tried to explain (a) the error and (b) how to handle it for what I guessed you were trying to do.  It'd be great to know if I was on the right track and if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidM: thanks. your answer was very good, but did not solve my problem completely ;)

Comment: What else is wrong?  Ask another question - link it here and I (and of course lots of other people as normal) will see it and have a look.

Answer (score 22):

My guess from your code is that you're trying to load a DLL or EXE into memory manually using something like [this technique](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) - is that right?  I'll address this at the end (pun intended) but first a quick explanation of why `VirtualAllocEx` is failing.

### Why is `VirtualAllocEx` giving this error?

The problem with allocating memory at a specific address is that there needs to be enough room at that address to allocate the memory size you request.  This is why, generally, when you request memory you let the OS decide where to put it.  (Plus letting the OS / malloc library decide can lead to other benefits, such as decreased fragmentation etc - out of scope for this answer.)

The problem you're getting is not that `VirtualAllocEx` is incapable of allocating 64MB rather than 4MB.  `VirtualAllocEx` can allocate (nearly) as much memory as you want it to.  The problem is that at the address you specify, in your process, there isn't 64MB of unallocated memory.

Consider hypothetical addresses 0-15 (0x0 - 0xF), where `-` marks empty memory and `x` marks allocated memory:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
x  x  -  x  -  -  -  -  x  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

This is your process's memory space.  Now, you want to allocate 4 bytes at address 0x4.  Easy - 0x4 to 0x7 are free, so you allocate and get (new allocation marked with X):

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
x  x  -  x  X  X  X  X  x  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

Fantastic.  But now suppose that instead you wanted to allocate 6 bytes.  There aren't six free bytes at address 0x4: there's some memory being used at 0x8:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
x  x  -  x  -  -  -  -  x  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
            1  2  3  4  bang!
```

You can't do it.  The problem isn't that the memory allocator can't handle allocating 6 bytes, but that the memory isn't free for it to do it.  Nor, most likely, can it shuffle the memory around - in a normal non-GC program you can't move memory to make space, because you might, say, leave dangling pointers which don't know the contents of the memory they were pointing at has changed address.  The only thing to do is either fail and not allocate memory at all, or allocate where it has free space, say at 0x9 or 0xA.

You might wonder why `VirtualAllocEx` is failing with `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` instead of `NULL`: most likely, it is because you specified an address it couldn't allocate at; thus, even though there is *some* free memory at that address (maybe) there isn't enough and the address isn't valid.  This is hinted at in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Attempting to commit a specific address range by specifying MEM_COMMIT
>   without MEM_RESERVE and a non-NULL lpAddress fails unless the entire
>   range has already been reserved. The resulting error code is
>   ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS.

This isn't quite your situation: you're specifying both flags at once, but if the method can't reserve then it effectively falls into this situation. It can't reserve the entire range *at that address*, so it gives error code `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`.

### Loading DLL or EXE images

So, what should you do with your problem, which I am *guessing* from your question and code is loading a DLL or EXE image in memory?

Here you need a bit of background on image locations in an EXE file.  Generally, an EXE is loaded into memory at the process's virtual address location 0x400000.  It's optional: your linker can ask it be put wherever, but [this value is common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833899/what-are-possible-reasons-for-not-mapping-win32-portable-executable-images-at-of).  Similarly, DLLs have a common default location: 0x10000000.  So, for one EXE and one DLL, you're fine: the image loader can almost certainly load them at their requested locations.

What happens when you have two DLLs, both asking to be located at 0x10000000?

The answer is *image rebasing*.  The image location is optional, it's not necessary.  Code inside the image that depends on being loaded at a specific address can be adjusted by the image loader, and so the second DLL might be loaded not at 0x10000000, but somewhere else - say, 0x1080000.  That's an address difference of 0x80000, and so the loader actually patches up a bunch of addresses and code inside the DLL so all the bits that thought they should refer to 0x10000000 now refer to 0x10800000.

This is really, really common, and every time you load an EXE this will be done to several DLLs.  It is so common that Microsoft have a little optimisation tool called [rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114492/whats-the-replacement-for-rebase-exe), (for "rebasing", that is, adjusting the base address) and when you distribute your EXE and your own DLLs with it, you can use this to make sure each DLL has a different base address, each of which is located so that when Windows loads your EXE and the DLLs they will already have the right addresses and it is unlikely to have to rebase - perform the above operation - on any of them.  For some applications this can make a noticeable improvement in starting time.  (In modern versions of Windows, sometimes DLLs are moved around anyway - this is for [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), a security technique to deliberately make sure code is not at the same address each time it's run.)

(One other thing is that some DLL and EXE compression tools strip out the data that is used for this relocation.  That's fine, because it makes the EXE smaller... right up until it needs to be relocated, and because the data is missing it can't, and so can't be loaded at all. Or you can [build with a fixed base, and it will magically work right until it doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957534/rebase-relocateimage-failed)  Don't do this to your EXEs or DLLs.)

So, what should you do when you try to manually load a DLL into memory, and there isn't enough space for it at the address it asks to be loaded at?  Easy - it's not a fatal error, just load it somewhere else, and then perform the rebasing yourself. I would suggest if you have problems to ask a new SO question, but to give you a starting point you can use the [`RebaseImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, or if you can't use it or want to do it yourself, I found [this code which from a quick overview seems to perform this manually](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fredrikjonsson/secureimplugin/master/CryptoPP/dllloader.cpp).  No guarantees about its correctness.

### TLDR

Your process address space doesn't have 64MB of empty space at the address you specify, so you can't allocate 64MB of memory there.  Instead, allocate it somewhere else and patch / rebase your loaded DLL or EXE image to match the new address.

Comment: Your answer solved my ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS problem. Been working on this for days. Now I know why VirtualAllocEx is failing randomly. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: @rtischer8277 Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use from NULL in address parameter:

```
void* pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,
               NULL,
               dwImageSize, 
               MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
               PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

> If lpAddress is NULL, the function determines where to allocate the
> region.

Note that for the rest of the code, use the `(void* pImageBase)`, not the `(INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase)`.