# Run a portable executable in memory - WinApi

Tags: c, winapi

Here is the code I currently have:

```
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD run_portable_executable(unsigned char* binary)
{
    BOOL success;
    const DWORD binary_address = (DWORD)binary;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* const dos_header = (LPVOID)binary;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* const nt_header = (LPVOID)(binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew);

    STARTUPINFOW startup_info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

    // Zero the structs to ensure valid values.
    SecureZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(startup_info));
    SecureZeroMemory(&process_info, sizeof(process_info));

    WCHAR current_file_path[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, current_file_path, MAX_PATH);

    // Use the current executable as a dummy process to be taken over by the binary.
    success = CreateProcessW(current_file_path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
        CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    CONTEXT ctx = 
    {
        .ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL
    };

    success = GetThreadContext(process_info.hThread, &ctx);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    // The following will occasionally fail because the fixed address of 0x400000 might
    // not be available or might not contain enough space.
    LPVOID const pe_base = VirtualAllocEx(process_info.hProcess, 
        (LPVOID)nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 
            nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, 
                PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if (!pe_base)
        goto err;

    success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, pe_base, binary,
        nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    const DWORD pe_base_address = (DWORD)pe_base;
    const DWORD end_of_pe_header = 
        binary_address + dos_header->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS);

    for (WORD i = 0; i < nt_header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i)
    {
        const DWORD section_offset = i * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER);
        const IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* const section_header = 
            (LPVOID)(end_of_pe_header + section_offset);

        LPVOID const section_base_address = 
            (LPVOID)(pe_base_address + section_header->VirtualAddress);

        LPCVOID const section_binary_buffer = 
            (LPVOID)(binary_address + section_header->PointerToRawData);

        success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, section_base_address, 
            section_binary_buffer, section_header->SizeOfRawData, NULL);

        if (!success)
            goto err;
    }

    // Ebx points to the PEB struct, where the 8 byte offset points to the
    // ImageBaseAddress member.
    LPVOID const modified_ebx = (LPVOID)(ctx.Ebx + 8);

    success = WriteProcessMemory(process_info.hProcess, modified_ebx, 
        &nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    ctx.Eax = pe_base_address + nt_header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

    success = SetThreadContext(process_info.hThread, &ctx);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    success = ResumeThread(process_info.hThread);

    if (!success)
        goto err;

    return 0;
err:
    return GetLastError();
}
```

This will work most of the time. The problem is here:

```
VirtualAllocEx(process_info.hProcess, (LPVOID)nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 
    nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

This will occasionally fail and return the `487` error code. I have found a highly relevant [question about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368429) which explained exactly what was going wrong. This virtual allocation would always happen at the fixed address of `0x400000` ([default for executables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx)), but if that address was currently unavailable at the time, it would return the `487` error code (invalid address).

My question is how should I handle this? I cannot simply set the second argument passed into `VirtualAllocEx()` to `NULL` as it would not match with the current image. The [question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368429) suggests using `ReBaseImage()`, but I do not know how this would be done for a portable executable in memory. The function requires the path to the `.exe` or `.dll` to then write the changes made to the image. How could this be done in memory?

**Edit:** [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999921/run-a-portable-executable-in-memory-winapi#comment85005473_48999921) proposed to relocate the image using `LdrProcessRelocationBlock`, a function from `ntdll.dll` which has the following signature:

```
IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION* WINAPI LdrProcessRelocationBlock(ULONG_PTR VA, ULONG SizeOfBlock,
    PUSHORT NextOffset, LONG_PTR Diff)
```

However, I am not sure how this could be used to move the image to rebase the image as the 3rd party documentation of this method is scarce. If anyone is familiar with its usage, an example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your original error code is `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES`. if your `PE` have relocations - it easy can be rebased in memory. so you need set 0 as address in `VirtualAllocEx` and rebase your image before copy to target process. but anyway image will be not full functional with this way running from memory

Comment: A PE file's specified `ImageBase` is just a suggestion, the OS is free to load a PE file at any available address it wants to.  Memory addresses stored in the PE header are relative to the actual load address that is used at runtime. In your case, don't use `nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase` at all, query `process_info.hProcess` for its actual load address instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How would I retrieve the load address from the process handle?

Comment: your image not loaded yet to target process. nothing to query.

Comment: @MichaelSmith: call `EnumProcessModules()` to get the process's loaded modules. The first module in the list is the file that the process was created from. Call `GetModuleInformation()` to get the load address of that module.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - all this not need. the `nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase` from binary module which OP want inject. it not loaded to target process yet. no sense query any modules. and at this stage - process yet not begin executed, loader structures not initialized - `EnumProcessModules` fail at this time

Comment: @RemyLebeau But the original process isn't necessarily the same size as the portable executable in memory. If the PE is larger than the space taken by that address, `VirtualAllocEx()` will still fail.

Comment: @RbMm You mentioned rebasing the image, how would this be done for a PE in memory? And would the `ReBaseImage()` function be used?

Comment: if relocation exist - very easy. first map pe to self process as image, than relocate it by using `LdrProcessRelocationBlock` and finally copy it to target process

Comment: what is funny - for what author of code allocate ctx by VirtualAlloc. why not simply declare it as local var

Comment: @RbMm I tried doing this originally and it does not work. I am not sure why, but it would not function properly unless the ctx variable was allocated.

Comment: absolute senseless. simply declare ctx as local variable. all perfect worked

Comment: @RbMm You are correct, I must have made a mistake earlier, it works as a local variable now!

Comment: @RbMm I was unable to find anything on `LdrProcessRelocationBlock`. Where does this method come from?

Comment: @MichaelSmith: it is a function of `ntdll.dll`, and as such is undocumented by Microsoft. 3rd party reverse-engineering sites have documented it, though.  Do a search online.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Are you aware that what you are doing is officially unsupported and liable to be broken by OS updates?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, this is simply an experimental project I am doing, none of this will be used in production code.

Comment: So save to disk and run from disk, easy

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The point of this project was to be able to run it in memory, of course running it as a file of its own would be no issue.

Comment: the last parameter or [`LdrProcessRelocationBlock`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntldr.h#L336) must be `INT_PTR` or `LONG_PTR` but not `int`. relocate mapped image very easy - https://pastebin.com/jK7RwDnm . so you first need map image in self process at `pvBuffer`, allocate `BaseAddress` in remote process, relocate image to this `BaseAddress` and copy it to remote. however all your idea how run code from memory - wrong from begin to end

Comment: I did not read the whole question and commends, but can't you just use [this approach](https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection/blob/178ba2a6a9feee0a9d9757dcaa65168ced588c12/dll/src/ReflectiveLoader.c#L369)?

Comment: So did the technique proposed by @RbMm work?

Comment: @HadiBrais I was unsure of the arguments of the function he provided, but when passing in `nt_header` along with the new address, the application failed with the error: "The application was unable to start correctly."

Comment: @HadiBrais - you mean call to `LdrProcessRelocationBlock` for relocate image - of course worked. strange question. however all this unrelated to run code from memory

Comment: if it's a problem with starting point on a specific point, then might can to write a temp code in between from that again chain call to this PE you want that I imagined must be large too???

Comment: @MichaelSmith - Hi. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebasing the PE image requires fixing up RVAs using the PE file's relocation table (usually in the `.reloc` section). If `VirtualAlloc` does not return memory at the preferred base address, you will indeed have to call `VirtualAlloc` again with `NULL` and perform fixups to the address space it returned you.

A public implementation of this is available from hasherezade's [libpeconv](https://github.com/hasherezade/libpeconv/blob/dea51f66b711662c2ce6b65d4644fa17f71ae6dc/libpeconv/src/relocate.cpp) library.

Comment: Please explain more